# Testing IntelliJ plugin on Idea Ultimate

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Default IntelliJ plugin debugger runs community version of IDE which doesn't have database support (which I want to debug). Adding debug configuration to idea.exe.vmoptions and connecting as remote debugger doesn't work. How to setup run configuration to launch IU version instead of IC? (Plugin project is Gradle project)

Comment: Have you checked the plugin's documentation first? See `version` property for `intellij` https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin#setup-dsl You can specify the editoin: `IC` - community or `IU` - ultimate.

Comment: thank you, everything works well